# Detecting output device in LaTeX

Tags: latex, postscript

Is there a way, in a LaTeX style/class file, to detect which output device is being used (or at least which capabilities it has)?  The reason is, I'm writing a class file in which I want to use some Postscript-specific packages (e.g. `pstricks`) if Postscript is available, but if I just write

```
\RequirePackage{pstricks}
```

then of course bad things happen if I'm compiling the document with `pdflatex`. So ideally I'm looking for something I can use like

```
\if@postscriptokay\RequirePackage{pstricks}\fi
```

It seems like this must be possible because I know packages like `pgf` can change their behavior to use appropriate graphics commands based on the output device, but I've done some Google searches and checked in my LaTeX book and haven't found a way.

Comment: I'm not sure this is stated in the best terms. You can detect what program is processing the source (with e.g. ifpdf), but I wouldn't describe that as "detecting the output device". YMMV. No good suggestion for a clearer formulation, however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  % nothing
\else
  \RequirePackage{pstricks}
\fi
```

Comment: This is the best you can do. Also see ifxetex, ifluatex.

Answer (score 6):

You can detect pdfTeX like this (this is what `ifpdf.sty` does):

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\pdfoutput\@undefined
  no pdfTeX
\else\ifnum\pdfoutput<1
  pdfTeX is outputting a .dvi file
\else
  pdfTeX is outputting a .pdf file
\fi\fi
```

graphicx.sty, hyperref.sty and pgf.sty have their own autodetection mechanisms built in. They load a different driver file (like `pdftex.def` and `hpdftex.def`) based on the autodetection and the package option. If you load any of these in your .tex file, try to get the information which driver they loaded. The relevant driver files are:

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-*.def
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/*.def
  /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
```

The name of the driver for `pgf.sty` and `graphicx.sty` is stored in the macro `\Gin@driver`. You can inspect this macro after loading any of these packages.

Comment: +1 nice explanation, although just using ifpdf is easier in practice (that's why I accepted the other answer).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at packages [pstool](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pstool.html) and [auto-pst-pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/auto-pst-pdf.html). They are here to help use `pstricks` and friends with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Actually I've never tried using pstool with pstricks; probably needs a bit more glue to make it user friendly. Let me know if otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [KOMA-Script](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) package (which I can really recommend, unless you need to use a different style of course) you already have a macro for this: `\ifpdfoutput{pdf output}{dvi output}` is defined in that package. If not, use the `ifpdf` package as has already been mentioned.